# How to validate a dynamically created table row data with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a form which has a dynamical table (a small part of that form) created at run time.It uses ng-repeat for table rows. I want to give validation on data of a row. I tried using ng-form but it did not work inside a table.

I want to display a error message when a particular column of a row is not filled or does not satisfy the constraint. How can I validate the row?

I am new to Angular.

Comment: Hey, Saurabh! First make it clear; Why do you need validation for a table? Does it contain inputs?